# debugging 'repo upload' problems - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, repository, gerrit

We're trying to set up a Gerrit instance for code reviews and are planning to use 'repo' with in.
I am able to push *directly to Gerrit*, but using `repo upload` fails with a public key error:

```
user@machine:~/workspace/git/gerrit-test$ repo upload
Upload project path/gerrit_test/ to remote branch master:
branch master ( 1 commit, Fri Aug 3 15:23:50 2012 -0700):
     8ef17a1b this better effin work
to gerrit.test.com:8081 (y/N)? y
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

----------------------------------------------------------------------
[FAILED] path/gerrit_test/ master          (Upload failed)
```

I have narrowed down the problem to the username that is being used for this repo, but have no idea where to set this user name (I'm not sure how to check what user name is being used either).
I've tried adding the following in **.repo/manifests.git/config** but it still fails.

```
[review "gerrit.test.com:8081"]
        username = <my_username_from_gerrit_profile_page>
```

Where do I add the correct user name?

Thanks.

Comment: For reference, a good way to debug this and see the URL (incl. the user name) `repo upload` is using is to use `GIT_TRACE=1 repo upload`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gerrit ssh server starts on port 29418, by default. You appear to be connecting to port 8081, which I suspect is the web server port number.

For confirmation check the following section of your "etc/gerrit.config" file:

```
[sshd]
    listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
    listenUrl = http://*:8081/
```

You can additionally check your private key credentials by running the following command:

```
$ ssh -p 29418 your_user_id@localhost

  ****    Welcome to Gerrit Code Review    ****

  Hi mark, you have successfully connected over SSH.

  Unfortunately, interactive shells are disabled.
  To clone a hosted Git repository, use:

  git clone ssh://your_user_id@your_machine:29418/REPOSITORY_NAME.git

Connection to localhost closed.
```

I think the reason you are able to "push directly to Gerrit" is because the ssh port number is part of the repository URL.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this & report when I'm back at work in two weeks.

Comment: @copolii Enjoy your vacation :-)

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you have your username in config file.

```
$ git config --global review.<"URL">.username $USER
```

Comment: It's really awkward this is indeed necessary in most of the cases as [repo by default uses the user email address as the username](https://android.googlesource.com/tools/repo/+/v1.12.33/git_config.py#652) instead of the name of the local user account.

Answer (score 2):

repo tool uses the prefix of your email as review.URL.username

For example,

**username**: john_chen

**Email**: John_Chen@gmail.com

**John_Chen** will be the review.URL.username.

therefore, you have to check whether you have the ability to connect through John_Chen

You can trace this by **repo --trace upload**